# Basic integral problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I tried solving the problem

$$\int_{a}^{b}2xy dx + \int_{a}^{b}z^{2}dx+ \int_{a}^{b}x^{2}dy + \int_{a}^{b}2zxdz$$

by integrating them individually and applying the limits **a=(0,1,2)** and **b=(5,2,7)** for which i got 590 as the answer.
I verified my answer here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B2xy%2Cx%5D%2BIntegrate%5BPower%5Bz%2C2%5D%2Cx%5D%2BIntegrate%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2Cy%5D%2BIntegrate%5B2zx%2Cz%5D

But when I tried solving them by grouping
$$\int_{a}^{b}(2xy dx+x^{2}dy)+\int_{a}^{b}(z^{2}dx+2zxdz)$$
and rewriting them as
$$\int_{a}^{b}d(x^{2}y)+\int_{a}^{b}d(z^{2}x)$$
I get the answer 295 after applying the limits.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: this $ \int_{a}^{b}2zxdz$ cannot be a number, as $x$ doesn't have a value. The same happen for all the other integrals

Comment: @Masacroso ... We take a curve in $3$-space, starting at $\mathbf{a}$ ending at $\mathbf{b}$.  Parameterize any way you like.  Compute this integral.  It has a value.

Comment: @GEdgar you can suppose that, but there is no curve in this question

Comment: I get 295; the same value for any curve.  Note that the problem given to Mathematica was not this, so no wonder it produced the wrong answer.

Comment: The curl of the vector field $(2xy+z^2,x^2,2zx)$ is zero, so the line integral is independent of the path.

Comment: The main thing you *can't* do for the integral you were apparently trying to evaluate is what you attempted, because when you integrated each component you were ignoring the fact that $x$, $y$ and $z$ all depend on each other.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, what do you have here?

The way the problem is set up doesn't make much sense.

I think you are considering a line integral from $(0,1,2)$ to $(5,2,7)$ of

$\int(2xy + z^2)\ dx + x^2\ dy + 2zx\ dz$

Since $f(x,y,z) = 2xy + z^2\ dx + x^2\ dy + 2xz \ dz = \nabla\cdot (x^2y + xz^2)$

We evaluate  $x^2y + xz^2|_{(0,1,2)}^{(5,2,7)} = 295$

We might say:
$\int 2xy + z^2\ dx = x^2y + xz^2 + f(y,z)\\ 
\int x^2\ dy = x^2y + g(x,z)\\ 
\int 2xz\ dz = xz^2 + h(x,y)$

And

$x^2y + xz^2 + f(y,z) = x^2y + g(x,z) = xz^2 + h(x,y)$

To arrive at $\nabla\cdot (x^2y + xz^2)$

Or, we can parameterize the curve:

$\int_0^1 (2(5t)(t+1)(5) + (5t+2)^2(5) + (5t)^2 + 2(5t)(5t+2)5 \ dt$

and you should get the same result.

But
$\int 2xy + z^2\ dx + \int x^2\ dy + \int 2xz\ dz = x^2y + xz^2 + x^2y + xz^2$

is not the correct way to evaluate a line integral.

Comment: **I think you are considering a line integral from (0,1,2) to (5,2,7) of

∫(2xy+z2) dx+x2 dy+2zx dz**

You're right. So you are saying that i can't integrate such functions without parameterizing them?

Comment: If you have a conservative function you don't have to parameterize.   This is the fundamental theorem of line integrals.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem.   And, if you have a closed curve, you have Green's theorem / Stokes's theorem to work for you.